# How to print python execution time with specific numbers from a random list to output both time and the random number generated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have been trying to calculate Python's execution time with this code, I've got the time but I don't know which number is being used from the list to be measured any help with how to print it would be helpful and much appreciated

```
import time
import random

def algorithm(c):
    b = []
    for i in c:
        b.append(i*2)

def data():
    c=[]
    for x in range(10000000):
        c.append(random.randint(1,100000))
timer(c)

def timer(c):
    time_start = time.time()
    algorithm(c)
    time_end = time.time()
    time_taken = time_end - time_start
    print(time_taken)
data()
```

Comment: need to fix your indentation

Comment: do you know about the `timeit` module?

Comment: I've seen it but never used it before

Answer (score 1):

I believe your code is fine you just need to restructure the code a bit.

```
import time
import random
import timeit
randomNumbersAndTime = {}
def algorithm(c):

    b = []
    for i in c:
        b.append(i*2)

def data():
    c=[]
    setupCode = "pass"
    print ("Random Number , Time Taken to Generate\n")
    for x in range(10000000):
        codeToExecute = str(random.randint(1,100000))
        randomNumb = timeit.timeit(stmt=codeToExecute, setup=setupCode, number=1000000)
        randomNumbersAndTime[codeToExecute] =  randomNumb

        for randomNumber in randomNumbersAndTime.keys() :            
            print ("{0} , {1} \n".format(randomNumber,randomNumbersAndTime[randomNumber]))

data()
```

this will give you the desired results.

**This is a sample output :**

```
Random Number , Time Taken to Generate

44806 , 0.433061423485 

44806 , 0.433061423485 

38079 , 0.44243301193 

44806 , 0.433061423485 

66713 , 0.435066187359 

38079 , 0.44243301193 

85426 , 0.422678350883 

44806 , 0.433061423485 

66713 , 0.435066187359 

38079 , 0.44243301193 

85426 , 0.422678350883
```

I hope i understood correctly .

Comment: I'm very thankful for the help, however not to sound ungrateful but I don't know which number is being used from the list to measure the execution time. would there be any way to print it? I apologise for being ungrateful

Comment: I have added comments to explain it a bit, you can always ask if it is still not clear.

Comment: sorry if I am not being clear. for example, I get the execution time which could be 17.623674392700195 what I need is the number that is used to calculate the 17.623674392700195. a number that isn't a float so that I get an output like                               
17.623674392700195, 45878269(random number)

Comment: you want to know the generation time of each random number, or the time it took to generate each random number?

Comment: no the random number by itself. sorry for the confusion

Comment: yes that is what I was looking for thank you so much I was having so much trouble with it you have my thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) module:

```
import timeit

codeToExecute = """

def algorithm(c):
    b = []
    for i in c:
        b.append(i*2)

algorithm(range(500))
"""

# 
setupCode = "pass"

meas =  timeit.timeit(stmt=codeToExecute, setup=setupCode, number=100000)

print(meas)
```

Output:

```
17.0021979809
```

This will execute the given function number times and print your time in seconds for it. You can use the setup to provide "data" or "imports" to your test that only has to be executed once and not on each run.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import random
import timeit
randomNumbersAndTime = {}
def algorithm(c):

    b = []
    for i in c:
        b.append(i*2)

def data():
    c=[]
    setupCode = "pass"
    print ("Random Number , Time Taken to Generate\n")
    for x in range(10000000):
        codeToExecute = str(random.randint(1,100000))
        randomNumb = timeit.timeit(stmt=codeToExecute, setup=setupCode, number=1000000)
        randomNumbersAndTime[codeToExecute] =  randomNumb

        for randomNumber in randomNumbersAndTime.keys() :            
            print ("{0} , {1} \n".format(randomNumber,randomNumbersAndTime[randomNumber]))

data()
```